# React - How to return a component with a dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return a component without a set name at runtime. Like so:

```
<div className="project-demo">
  <CustomComponent demo={project.demo}/>
</div>
```

and being called like this:

```
const CustomComponent = ({ demo }) => {

  return (
    <{ demo } />    
  )
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you  are trying to solve? I don't think what you are trying to do is recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSX expects components to have capitalized names](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

```
const CustomComponent = ({ demo }) => {
  const Demo = demo;
  
  return (
    <Demo />
  )
}
```

or better:

```
const CustomComponent = ({ Demo }) => {  
  return (
    <Demo />
  )
}
```